# Put value between 2 single quote Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `stringA='100,1000,11,9200';`

I want the out to be like this `stringA='100','1000','11','9200';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace along with some concatenation does it:

```
SQL> with test (a) as
  2    (select '100,1000,11,9200' from dual)
  3  select chr(39) || replace(a, ',', chr(39) ||','||chr(39)) || chr(39) new_a
  4  from test;

NEW_A
------------------------
'100','1000','11','9200'

SQL>
```

If you create that string (maybe using listagg?), then do it *at once*:

```
SQL> with test (a) as
  2    (select 100  from dual union all
  3     select 1000 from dual union all
  4     select 11   from dual union all
  5     select 9200 from dual
  6    )
  7  select chr(39) || listagg(a, chr(39) ||','|| chr(39)) within group (order by null) || chr(39) new_a
  8  from test;

NEW_A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'100','1000','11','9200'

SQL>
```

Comment: dear, is this solution will work if stringA values increase or decrease ??

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution. Replace all commas with ',' and concatenate the superscript in front of and after the string. In sql server it works, it should work for oracle as well.

```
SELECT ''''+REPLACE('100,1000,11,9200',',',''',''')+''''
```